# Some of my text all over the website underline automatically

Tags: html, css, underline

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but I don't want any text underline on my website and for some reason, it just got added automatically... any of you know how to fix it?

Is it because of the browser? The Stylesheet.css?

I'm really confuse since some of them are fine and other aren't...

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks

This is the website: [cliniquedukine.com](http://cliniquedukine.com)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrapped parts of your HTML markup with `<u>` elements which have a default style of `text-decoration: underline;` which comes from the user agent's default stylesheet.

I suggest amending the HTML markup to remove the `<u>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

you are using u tag in cliniquedukine.com
you are code:

```
 <u>410, 733 Boulevard Saint-Joseph <br> Gatineau, Québec <br> J8Y 4B6</u>
```

The default value of u tag is text-decoration: underline in chrome
So You have to redefine style of u tag.
you will do:

```
 <u style="text-decoration: initial;">410, 733 Boulevard Saint-Joseph <br> Gatineau, Québec <br> J8Y 4B6</u>
```

another method:
you are redefine u tag in stylesheet.css

```
u {
   text-decoration: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I putted the following code in my Stylesheet and now everything works fine: u {
   text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Found in your code

```
 <u>---, --- ********* ****-***** <br> *, *<br> --- ---</u>
```

u = underline

Answer (score -1):

Please link your code. Also in your stylesheet write this

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

see if that works

Comment: It's ALL the the text, not just links.